# Change route parameter in URL - Angular 2 with @ngrx/router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, ngrx

Trying to build a language picker and after picking a language change the URL (lang parameter only).

```
//app.routes.ts
{
   path: ':lang/register',
   component: RegisterComponent
}
```

If i go to example.com/en/register, I can use this code to get the value of the lang parameter.

```
routeParams$.pluck<string>('lang'); //returns 'en' when subscribing.
```

How can I change this value after changing language? And how can I get the full URL path?

Pseudo code:

```
var newLang = getFromLanguagePicker(); //returns 'se'
var updateLang = routeParams$.pluck<string>('lang').value = newLang;
```

Thanks

Comment: Couldn't you just set the routerLink of the picker when clicked (i'm assuming dropdown) to "/se/register" ?

Comment: Well, I assume I can do something like this, but not sure if it's the correct way to solve it?

`router.subscribe(
   function (x) {
    var newPath=x.path.replace(oldLang, newLang);
                                router.replace(newPath);
   },
   function (err) { },
   function () { });`

Comment: Subscribing to the params is only used for getting param values then do something with it ... not to manipulate the router path. You will still need to activate the route by doing a router.navigate. Either way you cannot just replace a string in the path, you'll have to pass the param to the router. Now as far as getting router information, inject ActivatedRoute into your constructor.

Comment: There is no ActivatedRoute in @ngrx/router. 

Ok, I will experiment some more and come back.

Comment: So sorry just realized your using ngrx, ng2 has it's similarities. I looked at the documentation and it looks like you can use router.search({ lang: se}) to update the current path. https://github.com/ngrx/router/blob/master/docs/overview/navigation.md

Comment: ..and for getting the current route information https://github.com/ngrx/router/issues/146

Comment: router.search({ lang: se}) updates the query parameter in the URL (i.e se/register?lang=se)

I want to change RouteParameter. Maybe I need to get the full path, do a search/replace in it and then navigate to it.